# Please help, how to update master table in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

"What I want to do is to update a summary field of the master table."

I have 3 tables, meals, orders and order_items.
Meal hasMany Order
Order hasMany OrderItem

```
class Meal extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'meals';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('Order', 'meal_id');
    }
}

class Order extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function meal() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Meal', 'meal_id');
    }

    public function orderItems() {
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem', 'order_id');
    }
}

class OrderItem extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'order_items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I use mass assignment to insert both 3 tables

```
$meal = Meal::create($mealData);
$order = Order::create($orderData);
$orderItem = OrderItem::create($orderItemData);
...
//I don't know what to do next
```

If I had a function in the Meal model, e.g. updateSummary(), after inserting those 3 tables how to call the updateSummary(), and how do I refer to the current meal_id which is just inserted???

This is what I've been working

```
public function updateSummary() {
  //using relationship
  $orders = $this->orders();
  //then use $orders to do some calculation
}
```

Can I call this from my controller

```
//after insert those 3 tables
$meal->updateSummary();
```

As I mentioned above, what I want is to update the summary field (amount_sum) of the master table (meals) after inserting data into the child tables, but I don't know what direction to go, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the meal_id**

the `create()` function, [creates the instance and also, importantly, *returns it*](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#_create)

```
$meal = Meal::create($mealData);
```

So, at this point, to get the `$meal_id` you just need to pull it from your model:

```
$meal_id = $meal->meal_id;
```

The same applies to your new instances of `$order`, and `$orderItem`.  Does that make sense?